# Formula for a geometric series weighted by binomial coefficients (sum over the upper index):$\sum_{i=0}^L {n+i\choose n}\ x^i =\ ?$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

The binomial sum is 
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}\ x^i = (1+x)^n,$$ 
where $\displaystyle{n\choose i}=\frac{n!}{(n-i)!i!}.$

Is there a corresponding formula when you sum over the upper index of the binomial coefficients, not the lower index:
$$\sum_{i=0}^L {n+i\choose n}\ x^i =\ ?$$
Equivalently, I am looking for the generating function of the sequence
$$a_i={r+i\choose k}\qquad i\ge0,$$
where $r\ge k\ge0$ are fixed parameters.

Comment: When you change upper index you continously change powers i think there isnt any closed form

Comment: There is a closed form which contains the incomplete beta function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a CAS

$$\sum_{i=0}^L {n+i\choose n}\ x^i =\frac{1-(L+1) \binom{L+n+1}{n} B_x(L+1,n+1) }{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$ where appears the incomplete beta function.

Comment: Is CAS some reference book?

Comment: **C**omputer **A**lgebra **S**ystem. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system