# Partial sums of binomial series

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients

I am working with the following function for integers $n,m$, defined in $[0,1]$.

$$f_{n,m}(x)= \sum_{i=0}^m \binom{n+i}{i}x^i$$

I know that this can be written as a hypergeometric function, using the binomial series. I am wondering if these kind of polynomials have been studied before... its properties in $[0,1]$, bounds, asymptotics, etc. Any reference will be of help.

Comment: Where does this particular function come from?  What are your studying?  I can see it's related to probability and combinatoric, but what problem is it derived from?

Comment: There's two queues of people, of lengths $l-n$ and $l-m$ respectively, and you want to compute the odds that one attains length $l$ before the other one. Here, $x$ is the probability of a person joigning one queue (and $1-x$ is the probability of joigning the other).

Comment: Since you said any reference is welcomed, at the risk of stating the obvious: this is related to the Negative Binomial distribution.

Comment: Well, it's not obvious for me since I was not familiar with this distribution. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just a couple of notes.

First, that you can rewrite $f_{n,m}(x)$ as
$$
\eqalign{
  & f_{\,n,\,m} (x) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m - k \cr 
  m - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  m - k \cr 
  m - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
   - n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m} \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
   - 1 \cr 
  m - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
   - n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$
so as to get rid of the summation bounds, which may be of advantage in the algebraic manipulation.

Second , that the formal series on $m$ has a neat and simple form
$$
\eqalign{
  & F_{\,n} (x,y) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,m} {f_{\,n,\,m} (x)y^{\,m} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,m} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} y^{\,m} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,m} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} y^{\,m} } }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,k} {\sum\limits_{k\, \le \,m\,} {\left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( {yx} \right)^{\,k} y^{\,m - k} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {1 - y}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,k} {\left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( {yx} \right)^{\,k} }  = {1 \over {1 - y}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( { - yx} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {1 - y}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,k} {\left( \matrix{
   - n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( { - yx} \right)^{\,k} }  = {1 \over {\left( {1 - y} \right)\left( {1 - xy} \right)^{\,n + 1} }} \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found something that satisfies me, coming from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684223/formula-for-a-geometric-series-weighted-by-binomial-coefficients-sum-over-the-u)  question:

$$f_{n,m}(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}\big(1-(m+1)\tbinom{n+m+1}{n}B_x(n+1,m+1)\big),$$

where $B_x$ is the incomplete Beta function. It was tough to find, probably because of the somewhat misleading title.

---

Interestingly enough, we have

$$(1-x)^{n+1}f_{n,m}(x) = x^{m+1}f_{m,n}(1-x),$$

following from the fact that the incomplete Beta functions are symmetric and the straightforward $(m+1)\tbinom{n+m+1}{n}=(n+1)\tbinom{n+m+1}{m}$.